# PayPal PRO (payflow) amount greater then 1000$

Tags: paypal, sylius, payum

I'm using `Sylius` with `payum/paypal-pro-checkout-nvp` in sandbox mode. When I'm trying to do direct payment with amount > 1000 USD I get `result code 12 - Error: Declined.`. Should I have the same situation for live mode or this is only sanbox behaviour ?

Comment: I think it's hard to answer this from a Sylius/Payum perspective. It's probably best to either find this in the documentation of PayPal, or be in contact with PayPal support to get a correct answer on this.

Comment: See [Result values based on amount submitted](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/payflow-pro/payflow-pro-testing/#credit-card-numbers-for-testing) . I assume this is just a feature of the PayPal sandbox environment and may not happen in live mode, unless you have a security feature set up in your PayPal account that limits the amount of the transaction.